# "react-native init project" command not working

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create react native project with following command but getting error, Help me gyus:

**react-native init Sample**

Following error occurs:

---

This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in D:\React_Demos\Sample
Using yarn v1.17.3
Installing react-native...
yarn add v1.17.3
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8888".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "D:\React_Demos\Sample\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
Error: Command failed: yarn add react-native --exact
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:657:15)
    at run (C:\Users\sachin.salunkhe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:294:5)
    at createProject (C:\Users\sachin.salunkhe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:249:3)
    at init (C:\Users\sachin.salunkhe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:200:5)
    at Object. (C:\Users\sachin.salunkhe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:777:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:788:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12) {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 10924,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
Command `yarn add react-native --exact` failed.

---

**Here is the yarn.log file:**

Arguments: 
  C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\sachin.salunkhe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js add react-native --exact

PATH: 
  C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Users\sachin.salunkhe\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\adb;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.5.4;\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin;C:\Users\sachin.salunkhe\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\sachin.salunkhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\;C:\Users\sachin.salunkhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\sachin.salunkhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\sachin.salunkhe\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin

Yarn version: 
  1.17.3

Node version: 
  12.7.0

Platform: 
  win32 x64

Trace: 
  Error: https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8888
      at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\sachin.salunkhe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:151950:17)
      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:20)
      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:203:13)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:399:9)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:203:13)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
      at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)

npm manifest: 
  {"name":"Sample","version":"0.0.1","private":true,"scripts":{"start":"node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"}}

yarn manifest: 
  No manifest

Lockfile:

### No lockfile

Comment: Did you install react-native globally ? with -g?

Comment: **Yes** i have run that command

Comment: react native -v ? what did you get ?

Comment: i get this

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Comment: it's not installed correctly i think , try to uninstall and install react-native-cli 
follow these commands : npm uninstall -g react-native-cli && npm install -g react-native-cli

Comment: i did that but it says:

error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8888"

Comment: Follow these commands 
npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set strict-ssl false

Comment: Same error occured, is there any problem with my PC

Comment: npm -v , nodejs - v which output

Comment: npm -v = 6.10.0 , node -v=v12.7.0

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: yes, after re-installing everything. solved problem

Answer (score 3):

First You Can Run This Command,

sudo npm install -g react-native-cli

then after run this command,

react-native init Sample

Comment: Did you try npm install -g react-native-cli ?

Comment: Or try to install it as an Administrator

Comment: Yes, i did that but it seems problem with yarn

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have carried out this course.

1. `choco install -y nodejs.install python2 jdk8` // If there is no choco, [install it.](https://chocolatey.org/)
2. `npm install -g react-native-cli`
3. Download and install `Android Studio` // and setting Configure the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable. and new SDK
4. `react-native init AwesomeProject`

Comment: Yes, I have all setup done. I have also created one project by using that. But now it's showing me the error.

Comment: what is yarn? Did you had yarn in window??

Answer (score 0):

First, remove node modules then install it again then install react-native cli. After that run init command.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful for him.

```
1) Remove node_modules then update react native-cli with latest version.
2) npm install
3) react-native link
4) After that this command : react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to your npm folder before issuing the command, it should work, then you can always move the folder.
So
    cd C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm

Then run

```
react-native init AppName
```